# recycler view not showing Items while fetching data from firebase

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I was trying to make note making app with firebase firestore and kotlin. There is no data present at the compile time. When the app get executed and user will move to my notes activity I just want to store user's entered string in firebase firestore and then want to retrieve all that data to my app's recycler view. Can anyone provide me this problem solution.

Below is my whole code where I have written the fetching functionality of data for my app.

please Help me to solve this Problem

```
class NotesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var createnotefab: FloatingActionButton

    lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
    lateinit var firebaseFirestore: FirebaseFirestore

    val db = Firebase.firestore

    lateinit var mrecyclerview: RecyclerView
    lateinit var staggeredGridLayoutManager: StaggeredGridLayoutManager

    private val items:ArrayList<FirebaseModel> = ArrayList()

    lateinit var noteAdapter:FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<FirebaseModel, NoteViewHolder>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes)

        createnotefab = findViewById(R.id.createnotefab)

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        val user = firebaseAuth.currentUser

        title = "All Notes"

        createnotefab.setOnClickListener {    
            startActivity(Intent(this, CreateNoteActivity::class.java))        
        }

        val query =
            db.collection("notes").document(user.toString()).collection("myNotes")
                .orderBy("title", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)


        val allusernotes = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<FirebaseModel>()
            .setQuery(query, FirebaseModel::class.java)
            .setLifecycleOwner(this).build()

        noteAdapter =
            object : FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<FirebaseModel, NoteViewHolder>(allusernotes) {
                override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NoteViewHolder {

                    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                        .inflate(R.layout.notes_layout, parent, false)

                    return NoteViewHolder(view)
                }

                override fun onBindViewHolder(
                    holder: NoteViewHolder,
                    position: Int,
                    model: FirebaseModel
                ) {

                    holder.notetitle.setText(model.getTitle())
                    holder.notecontent.setText(model.getContent())

                }    
            }    

        mrecyclerview = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview)
        mrecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)
        staggeredGridLayoutManager =
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
        mrecyclerview.layoutManager = staggeredGridLayoutManager
        mrecyclerview.adapter = noteAdapter
    }

    class NoteViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val notetitle: TextView
         val notecontent: TextView
        val mnote: LinearLayout

        init {
            notetitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notetitle)
            notecontent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notecontent)
            mnote = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note)
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        noteAdapter.startListening()
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        if (noteAdapter != null) {
            noteAdapter.stopListening()
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        startActivity(Intent(this,HomeFragment::class.java))
    }    
}
```

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: If you add some logging to `onBindViewHolder`, do you see that logging appear in the logcat output? If not, the problem is in loading of the data. If you do, the problem is in its display. If it's the former, can you edit your question to show a screenshot of the Firebase console showing a document that you'd expect to show up?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please respond with @.